# PHP - Weather System Interface

Tags: web-apps, php, weather

I'm looking for an alternative to [OpenWeatherMap.org](http://openweathermap.org/), which is a online Weather System Interface. I would like the application to be written in PHP.

Thank you!

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for an entire Weather System or just a widget? Here are two possible solutions,

**[Simple Weather System](http://codecanyon.net/item/simple-weather-system/5787138)** (Commercial, $9 - Lifetime Updates)

> Simple Weather System is an light weather script that simply does his
>   job. By default it comes with two providers and multiple themes. It’s
>   can auto-detect user location by ip or by web browser navigator.
>   Feautures:
>
> - Multiple providers
> - Geoip localisation
> - Multiple themes
> - Multiple language support
> - Easy to extend
> - API support
> - Cache
> - Metric/Imperial units
> - Multiple providers
> - Very configurable
> - Easy to install
>
> [image: Simpel Weather System User Interface]

If your looking for a simple weather widget, then this will also work,

**[php-weather-widget](https://github.com/metwit/php-weather-widget)** (Open Source)

> How to create a simple PHP weather widget to show real time weather in a given location, 
>   using Metwit’s Weather API and with the help of Mashape, which will provide us an SDK ready to use with Metwit APIs.